# Run a program multiple times in C

Tags: c, loops

I am a newbie to programing, so excuse my ignorance. And I didn't get the answer properly here in this site. It can be my searching incapability. 
In C I've written a code which is running fine. But I want to run the code as many time as the user wishes it to. That means, suppose after executing the Triangle area problem, user can run the program again and again. What needs to be done here? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{     

      char a;
      int base, hight, radius, length, width;
      float area, pi=3.14;
      printf("\n\tEnter T to execute the area of Triangle"
      "\n\tEnter R to execute the area of Rectangle"
      "\n\tEnter C to execute the area of Circle\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t");
      a=getche();
      printf("\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t");
      if(a=='T' || a=='t'){
                 printf("You want to know the Area of a Triangle."
                 "\n\tEnter your triangles Base: ");
                 scanf("%d", &base);

                 printf("\n\tEnter your triangles Hight: ");
                 scanf("%d", &hight);

                 printf("\n\tThe base is %d and the hight is %d." 
                 "So the area of your triangle is: \n\n\t\t\t\t", base,hight);

                 area= .5*base*hight;
                 printf("%f", area);
      }

       else if(a=='R' || a=='r'){
                 printf("You want to know the Area of a Rectangle."
                 "\n\tEnter your rectangles Length: ");
                 scanf("%d", &length);

                 printf("\n\tEnter your rectangles Hight: ");
                 scanf("%d", &hight);

                 printf("\n\tThe length is %d and the hight is %d." 
                 "So the area of your Rectangle is: \n\n\t\t\t\t", length,hight);

                 area= length*hight;
                 printf("%f", area);
     }

      else if(a=='C' || a=='c'){
                 printf("You want to know the Area of a Circle."
                 "\n\tEnter your circles Radius: ");
                 scanf("%d", &radius);

                 printf("\n\tThe Radius is %d." 
                 "So the area of your Circle is: \n\n\t\t\t\t", radius);

                 area= pi*radius*radius;
                 printf("%f", area);
      }else{
            printf("Invalid Input");
      }


      getch();

}
```

Comment: BTW, `conio.h` is obsolete now.

Answer (score 5):

Introduce a boolean variable, say `repeat`. Then set up an infinite loop with `do` and `while` that repeats as long as `repeat` is true. After the calculation, ask the user if he or she would like to continue; the result could be read with `scanf`. Then, set `repeat` accordingly, which means that the infinite loop is terminated as soon as `repeat` gets false.

Comment: @PaulR Indeed, `continue` is a keyword, thanks for the remark.

Comment: @user3663862 Yes, In C I have seen the idiom `for(;;)` to use an unconditional infinite loop, which can be left with `break`.

Comment: where should i put this loop? before the first printf?
Thanks for your quick response brother.