# How to play and replay small c program

Tags: c

The book I'm currently reading asked me to make a program similar to this (but I decided to make it so we can interact with it) and I was wondering, how do I make it so I can play and replay with it? for example, "Do you want to play? no=0 yes=1" and whenever you finished playing it would ask you if you want to play again. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int num;
    printf ("How many elements?\n");
    scanf ("%i", &i);
    printf ("Incicialize number?\n");
    scanf ("%i", &num);
    int v[i];

 inic(v, i, num) ;
}

 int inic (int s[], int i, int num)
 {
     int n;
     for (n=0;n<i;n++){
        s[i] = num;
        printf("Incializar %i = %i\n", n+1, s[i]); }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a program multiple times in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800549/run-a-program-multiple-times-in-c)

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  It has two major problems. 1) the function signature for `inic()` is not defined before it  is called.  2) The function: `inic()` has a return type of  `int` but the actual function never returns any value (and the calling function: `main()` fails to check for a return value.  Suggest changed the signature to: `void inic (int s[], int i, int num)` and insert a prototype for that function before the function: `main()`\

Comment: regarding: `#include <stdlib.h>`  Nothing in the header file: `stdlib.h` is being used by the posted code.  It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `do - while loop` with the option to be in the while expression.

```c
do {

// your program

int option;
printf("do you want to play? no=0 yes=1\n");
scanf("%d", &option);

} while(option);
```

Comment: this answer fails to check the returned value from the call to `scanf()`, so when `scanf()` fails, the value in `option` (the first time through the loop) is what ever trash happened to be in memory/stack where that variable is located.  AND if the user enters `0` then execution will stay in that loop.

Comment: suggest replacing: `while(option)` with: `while( option != 0 && option != 1)`